# Electronic Chess Board

Tags: sensor, wire, magnetics, code

I want to make a chess board that can detect where all of the pieces are and send this information to a computer (Chess.com). I looked into it, and it seems that the best way to do this would be with a sensor or magnet in each individual piece and one under each square on the board. However, I have absolutely no idea how to hook everything up and make it work. I am utterly ignorant about electronics. So if anyone is willing to give up some of their free time and help me, it would be much appreciated.

I'm trying to hook this up to a board that's made of wood, whose squares are about 1" by 1" and are about 3/8 inches thick, and I don't want to cut the wood if possible.

(Preferably less complicated electronics)

Comment: "*So if anyone is willing to give up some of their free time and help me ...*" That's not really how this site works. SE sites are designed for specific focused questions which can be answered directly. There's a good [Tour] that explains this. There should be many articles available explaining how to create an 8 x 8 matrix (it's exactly the same as a keyboard matrix). Most of the work has been done many, many times.

Comment: I can think of several ways of doing this: NFC in each square and piece base, electrical contacts to read some in-piece memory, computer vision to translate a camera on a chessboard into piece positions. But all of these options are serious design projects requiring months of effort, tinkering, experimentation and design. We can't help you set your design goals but once you have put in some work on a design and have a concrete problem with implementation, *that* would probably be a better question for this site.

Comment: Use something like an RFID reader ... with 2 analog multiplexers (x and y) ... (?)

Answer (score 1):

The issue you’re overlooking is *knowing which piece is on each square.*

My suggestion? Overhead camera with an AI classifier to identify which piece is which.

A couple of examples:

https://towardsdatascience.com/board-game-image-recognition-using-neural-networks-116fc876dafa

https://tech.bakkenbaeck.com/post/chessvision

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8321354/

Lots more if you look - it's a popular project. By now there are probably versions that run on phones - so zero hardware.

Comment: in chess only one piece moves at a time, so the computer just needs to remember where all the pieces are and detect changes.

Comment: True; it also has to know / figure out when a piece is taken, implying rules of chess knowledge by the thing reading the sensors. Now, if a piece could make more than one move that can take an opponent’s piece (admittedly a rare case) there would be ambiguity. Nonetheless a camera + computer + AI would be the least  effort. Here’s on on GitHub: https://github.com/SukritGupta17/Chess-Board-Recognition

Comment: And another: https://github.com/andrefakhoury/chess-board-recognition

Comment: @hacktastical if the system detects detect the temporary absence of the removed piece there is never an ambiguity.  A camera + image processing will surely work, but feels a little heavy for something you can do with 64 switches of one kind or another.

Comment: @jonathanjo You are right. It's kind of "heavy." (Though these days 32- and 64- processors are getting to be a dime a dozen. Same with cameras.) The only problem with the much simpler approach (say: magnets and reed relay ampules) is that if a unique setup has to be placed (not the usual starting positions), then some means of saying "what is what" needs some provision. That may not be hard. But it will be necessary.

Comment: @jonk of course I agree with you, but I've always loved this as a design problem (I give it to students)..  My favourite solutions are 1/4-in jack plug + resistance, bidirectional hall effect + magnets, and RFID readers.  But obviously there are loads of ways of doing it.  OP: read up on `hall effect sensor arduino`, look for sensors which give different signal on N or S poles.  This will be the most discreet solution (no overhead camera, no cutting of board; need to pieces to put magnets.)